# Solr indexing raises error while posting file

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using **Solr 6.4.1** version and I recently posted around 1000 files to the solr for indexing. I used **Windows Powershell** in Windows 10 to post the files using the command.

> PS C:\solr-6.4.1> java -Dc=Solr_sample -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files
>   -Drecursive=yes -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar E:\Test\

But among them I found that one file is not indexed and I tried to index that particular file using the following command again but no luck. The file is 212MB in size. I have attached the error and all below. Could you please help me posting this file to Solr indexing.

```
PS C:\solr-6.4.1> java -Dc=Solr_sample -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar E:\Test\C0000000045\
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/Solr_sample/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
Entering recursive mode, max depth=999, delay=0s
Indexing directory E:\Test\C0000000045 (1 files, depth=0)
POSTing file 20162436739-Spheres Volume 3 Foams Plural Spherology. Peter Sloterdijk. MIT.pdf (application/pdf) to [base]/extract
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #500 (Server Error) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/Solr_sample/update/extract?resource.name=E%3A%5CTest%5CC0000000045%5C20162436739-Spheres+Volume+3+Foams+Plural+Spherology.+Peter+Sloterdijk.+MIT.pdf&literal.id=E%3A%5C
Test%5CC0000000045%5C20162436739-Spheres+Volume+3+Foams+Plural+Spherology.+Peter+Sloterdijk.+MIT.pdf
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/Solr_sample/update/extract. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.InputStreamSource.&lt;init&gt;(InputStreamSource.java:39)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser.&lt;init&gt;(PDFObjectStreamParser.java:55)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectStream(COSParser.java:821)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:727)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:652)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseDictObjects(COSParser.java:612)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:215)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:249)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:972)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:908)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:131)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
        at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:166)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2306)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
</pre>

</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/Solr_sample/update/extract?resource.name=E%3A%5CTest%5CC0000000045%5C20162436739-Spheres+Volume+3+Foams+Plural+Sp
herology.+Peter+Sloterdijk.+MIT.pdf&literal.id=E%3A%5CTest%5CC0000000045%5C20162436739-Spheres+Volume+3+Foams+Plural+Spherology.+Peter+Sloterdijk.+MIT.pdf
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/Solr_sample/update...
Time spent: 0:00:13.795
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other answers, I came to know that the error was because of memory but the following command solved my issue.

> PS C:\solr-6.4.1> bin\solr start -m 4g

I increased the Solr memory to 4 GB which solved my problem.

Alternatively, we could also create a Task on Windows Task Scheduler to run Solr with the following arguments:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the jvm is running out of ram, as you are not explicitely setting the heap size, the jvm is using a default value. Extracting text from a pdf might take a lot of ram, so you can try giving Solr as much as you can (mind you, for this particular case, not in general Solr usage), so start solr with more ram. That depends on how you are starting it now, if you are using the built in service, edit solr.in.sh adn uncomment/modify this line

```
#SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xmx8g-Xmx8g"
```

if you have for instance 8gb free to use (adapt to your case)

Comment: I used the command PS C:\solr-6.4.1> java -Xmx8g -Dc=Solr_sample -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar E:\Test\C0000000045\ but it is still giving same error.

Comment: how much ram do you have free? give it as much as you can. But you cant rule out a bug in pdf text extraction, you might never get the text out of it (or you could but by other means, then create a doc in solr with that text manually/script if it is that important)

Comment: The error message is generated on the server, giving the indexing tool more memory won't help. You can change the size of the allocated memory in/for the Solr startup script you're using.

Comment: duh...you are correct. That is what I meant (when I say 'start solr with more ram') but then got distracted and commented about the client command...Updated the answer

Comment: I just changed the file located at solr-6.4.1\bin\solr.in.sh and uncomment and modified to SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms6g -Xmx6g" and restarted the solr with the command PS C:\solr-6.4.1> bin\solr start  but still getting the same problem.

Comment: if that is all the ram you have, then refer to my first comment